Docker build stopped working after Ubuntu software update
Docker build was ok, and the Python script (app) that was inside could be executed perfectly too. I hadn't touched the code for some months now, but I recently did a general, across-system software update in my Oracle VM VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64. I thought this wouldn't affect my docker, since I had specified package versions, etc.
However, when I try to docker build now it cannot find TensorFlow 2.12.0, and says that only 12.16.0rc and 12.16.1 are available. How can I make it see the 2.12.0 version again? Here is my Dockerfile:
# Build stage
FROM python:3.7-slim AS build
WORKDIR /todo

ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget \
https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
&& mkdir /root/.conda \
&& bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
&& rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh 
RUN conda --version
RUN apt-get --purge autoremove -y wget

RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --no-deps tensorflow-cpu==2.12.0 # <--- ERROR HERE

# Runtime stage
FROM python:3.7-slim
WORKDIR /todo

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=build /root/miniconda3 /root/miniconda3
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY get_predict_m_data.py get_predict_m_data.py

ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ENV PATH="/usr/local/lib/:${PATH}"

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV PORT 5556
EXPOSE 5556

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

CMD ["python", "-u", "get_predict_m_data.py"]

Error:
gsamaras@lv74744332234a:~/Code$ sudo docker build --no-cache -t predict_api .
[sudo] password for gsamaras: 
[+] Building 36.1s (14/23)                                                                                                                                                                  docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.68kB                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim-buster                                                                                                                             3.4s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [build 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim-buster@sha256:9bd2bfc822a533f99cbe6b1311d5bf0ff136f776ebac9b985407829f17278935                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 533B                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/8] WORKDIR /todo                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [build 3/8] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                                                                                    6.5s
 => CANCELED [stage-1  3/12] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                                                                            32.7s
 => [build 4/8] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*                                                                                                          2.9s
 => [build 5/8] RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh && mkdir /root/.conda && bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-  20.8s
 => [build 6/8] RUN conda --version                                                                                                                                                                   0.5s
 => [build 7/8] RUN apt-get --purge autoremove -y wget                                                                                                                                                0.5s
 => ERROR [build 8/8] RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --no-deps tensorflow-cpu==2.12.0                                                                                                       1.4s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 > [build 8/8] RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --no-deps tensorflow-cpu==2.12.0:                                                                                                                  
1.094 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-cpu==2.12.0 (from versions: 2.16.0rc0, 2.16.1)                                                                             
1.094 ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-cpu==2.12.0                                                                                                                                     
------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Dockerfile:22                                                                                                                                                                                              
--------------------                                                                                                                                                                                       
  20 |     RUN apt-get --purge autoremove -y wget                                                                                                                                                          
  21 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  22 | >>> RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --no-deps tensorflow-cpu==2.12.0                                                                                                                       
  23 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  24 |     # Runtime stage
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c python -m pip install --no-cache-dir --no-deps tensorflow-cpu==2.12.0" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


If I go with a newer TF version, then a chain reaction happens with many dependencies getting broken, I can show the requirements.txt too if needed. If I update all the dependencies (and install new required packages), then I am getting a series of runtime errors, which when I fix, I hit compatibility issues (Keras 2 with Keras 3 trained models), which requires a lot of work; thus I seek a way to work with TF 2.12.0, in order for everything to be harmonized.

What pip version do you have?

You mean in my VM in general @AndréLehto? I don't have python, pip, or pip3. I have python3 in terminal of this version Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 22 2023, 10:22:35).

Yes, but pip has it's own version inside of Python, I had an idea that the version of pip might not support the version of tensorflow-gpu. But nevermind that, see my answer below, it probably solves your issue.

@AndréLehto but I am using tensorflow-cpu. Why would the GPU version affect this? If I try to install tensorflow instead, I get the same version errors.

Please read my answer below. tensorflow-gpu has been removed. Please install tensorflow instead. The tensorflow package supports GPU accelerated operations via Nvidia CUDA.

@AndréLehto I am not using GPU. In any case, I tried your answer, same error.

Looking at the pypi package for tensor tensorflow-gpu, it seems that package has been removed. They write the following:

Projekt-Beschreibung
tensorflow-gpu has been removed. Please install tensorflow instead. The tensorflow package supports GPU accelerated operations via Nvidia CUDA.
Removal Information
tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu have been the same package since TensorFlow 2.1, released in September 2019. Although the checksums differ due to metadata, they were built in the same way and both provide GPU support via Nvidia CUDA. As of December 2022, tensorflow-gpu has been removed and has been replaced with this new, empty package that generates an error upon installation.
All existing versions of tensorflow-gpu are still available, but the TensorFlow team has stopped releasing any new tensorflow-gpu packages, and will not release any patches for existing tensorflow-gpu versions.
About this package
This simple package raises a warning if setup.py is executed as part of a package installation. This intentionally prevents users from installing the package.

Try changing tensorflow-cpu==2.12 to tensorflow==2.12

Edit:
As can be seen on the pypi package for tensorflow, the minimum required version of python is 3.8. You are using 3.7. Try updating from:
FROM python:3.7-slim AS build to FROM python:3.8-slim AS build

Same error, no matching version. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.12.0 (from versions: 2.16.0rc0, 2.16.1).

Andre apologies, I forgot to mention that I had tried that already with 3.8 and 3.9 (which I think is the minimum https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.12.0/). Same error. Also, if that was the problem, it wouldn't explain why 3.7 was working some months ago.

I successfully installed sensorflow 2.12.0 using python3 -m pip install tensorflow==2.12.0 using Python 3.10.6. Have you tried updating using Python 3.8 (or better yet Python 3.9) AND change tensorflow-cpu==2.12.0 to tensorflow==2.12.0?

Ander I was just about to write this: If I use 3.8-slim-buster and then RUN python3.8 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --no-deps tensorflow-cpu==2.12.0, it finds it! :) However, I am waiting for the build to finish. Then I need also to run the app to check. However, I don't get why it was working before with 3.7-slim-buster! Anyway, I am going to update you ASAP.

Please do! The reason is probably that Google decided to remove the repository for tensorflow-gpu AND raise the required python version. Compatability can be a *** sometimes.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
